# Laurent Series with Symbolic Powers

Tags: series-expansion, assumptions

I'm having trouble getting Mathematica to expand expressions in a Laurent series when the expansion parameter is raised to symbolic powers.

As an example, consider:

> Assuming[{a > 0, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, c3 > 0}, Normal[Series[a^(-c2)/((a*c1)^(c2) + c3), {a, 0, 0}]]]

I want this to take $\frac{1}{a^{c_2}}\frac{1}{(a c_1)^{c_2}+c_3}$ and expand about $a=0$ to zeroth order in $a$.

The result should be $\frac{1}{c_3}\frac{1}{ a^{c_2}}-\frac{c_1^{c_2}}{c_3^2}$, but instead I just get back $\frac{1}{a^{c_2}}\frac{1}{(a c_1)^{c_2}+c_3}$ again.  No expansion takes place at all.  I.e. the result is:

> a^(-c2)/((c1*a)^(c2) + c3)

Are there extra Assumptions that need to be added?

Comment: You are trying to expand at a discontinuity.  

`Assuming[{a > 0, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, c3 > 0}, 
 Limit[a^(-c2)/((a*c1)^c2 + c3), a -> 0]]` evaluates to 

`Infinity`

Comment: That's not the problem.  That's what a Laurent series does.  If you replace, say, c1, c2 and c3 by 1 then Mathematica returns 1/a-1 which is the right answer in this limiting case.  More generally, it should return what I have written above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) does not work with symbolic powers. Here is a simple example:

```
Series[x^n, {x, 0, 5}]
```

> x^n

To see why,  note that [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) (when it works) evaluates to a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData) object:

```
Series[x, {x, 0, 1}] //InputForm
```

> SeriesData[x, 0, {1}, 1, 2, 1]

Let's look at the [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData) documentation:

```
WolframLanguageData["SeriesData","PlaintextUsage"]
```

"SeriesData[x, x0, {a0, a1, …}, nmin, nmax, den] represents a power 
series in the variable x about the point x0 . The ai are the coefficients in 
the power series. The powers of (x - x0) that appear are nmin / den, (nmin + 1) / den, …, nmax / den."

So, a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData) representation of $x^n$ would look something like:

```
SeriesData[x, 0, {1}, n, n+1, 1]
```

> SeriesData::sdatn: Order specification n in SeriesData[x,0,{1},n,1+n,1] is not a machine-sized integer.
>
> SeriesData[x, 0, {1}, n, 1 + n, 1]

which isn't supported. This is why a naive application of [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) to your expression doesn't work.

One possibility is to just replace your variable with one whose powers are all explicit integers, and then use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
e = PowerExpand[
    a^(-c2)/((a*c1)^(c2) + c3) /. a -> z^(1/c2),
    Assumptions -> z>0 && c1>0 && c2>0 && c3>0
]
```

> 1/(z (c3 + c1^c2 z))

Now, we can use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
s = Series[e, {z, 0, 0}];
s //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{\text{c3} z}-\frac{\text{c1}^{\text{c2}}}{\text{c3}^2}+O\left(z^1\right)$

Convert back, after converting the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) object back to a normal expression:

```
r = Normal[s] /. z -> a^c2
r //TeXForm
```

> -(c1^c2/c3^2) + a^-c2/c3
>
> $\frac{a^{-\text{c2}}}{\text{c3}}-\frac{\text{c1}^{\text{c2}}}{\text{c3}^2}$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.  That's disappointing, re: the way Series works.  I thought about that same workaround, but was hoping not to resort to that.  Oh well.

Comment: So, if I instead wanted to run a series expansion on something like 
    a^(-c2)/(a^(c2) + a), expanding in a, what could I do? Your trick doesn't work in this scenario, it seems.  Unless you can get Mathematica to separately replace instances of a^(c2) alone, I guess.

Comment: Is `c2` an integer, a rational, an exact irrational, or a machine number?

Comment: I need it to be an arbitrary positive number.

Comment: "That's disappointing, re: the way `Series` works." What exactly were you expecting? You are giving it a symbolic singularity it cannot unravel.

Comment: I told you in the original post what I expected: for Series to accurately produce the correct Laurent series.  If I can do it in two seconds by hand, I expect mathematica can do it as well.

Comment: Firstly, it's not a Laurent series if it has symbolic powers. And a `SeriesData` object, which implements Puiseux series in *Mathematica*, requires rational (or integer) exponents. These are the objects that can be supported in terms of performing series algebra operations. Symbolic exponents take one out of that class. This does not mean one cannot do algebra using symbolic exponents using the Wolfram language, it simply means `Series` alone will not be a sufficient tool for such a task.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right on the first point.  Laurent series is not the right word for general $c_1$.  I would, however, be happy if Mathematica could apply Series while assuming $c_1$ to be integer, in which case it's an honest Laurent series.  But this I haven't gotten this to work.  Is there no other function which can do such an expansion?

Comment: (1) Playing around with it I did substitutions for `a^c2` and related powers so that ordinary `Series` could be used. Then read this answer by @CarlWoll more carefully and realized it was equivalent to his. So I'd say this is a reasonable way to go about it.

Comment: (2) Assuming `c1` to be an integer is not sufficient for purposes of `Series` because it requires explicit integer powers (to do ordering, have a "lowest" power and fixed size steps above that, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, your point (2) is essentially the answer I was looking for (which is what I was finding disappointing).  And unfortunately your (1) works in the toy example I posted, but not in the more complicated example I'm actually interested in.  But maybe a modification can.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @user26866 What do you want returned for something like `Exp[a^c1] + Exp[a^c2]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll In that example a power series in $a^{c_1}$ plus a power series in $a^{c_2}$ would be fine.